# Load html page that is in a different directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where when a link is clicked, additional HTML will be loaded to the page. The HTML fragment file I'd like to load is located in a different folder within my project. I am unable to accomplish the .load portion without getting a 404 not found. The page I am on when clicking the link is "http://localhost:8000/esr_dashboard/request_details/469/". When I click the link it returns the 404 with "http://localhost:8000/esr_dashboard/request_details/469/esr_dashboard/esr_msg_detail.html"

Folder structure for js file and desired html file as follows. Note, I am working a django project.

```
EGHub (django project)
├── esr_dashboard (app folder)
│   ├── templates
│       ├── esr_dashboard
│           ├── esr_msg_detail.html
├── static
│   ├── js
│       ├── script.js
```

```js
$(.msg_detail_link).on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id")
  console.log(id)
  $.get('/esr_dashboard/request_message_details/'+id+'/',
    function(data, status) {
      obj = JSON.parse(data)
      // test to confirm the data is good
      console.log(obj[0].fields.first_name + " " +obj[0].fields.last_name)
  });
  $("#row_msg_detail").load('./esr_msg_detail.html')
});
```

Comment: Try with this snippet `$("#row_msg_detail").load('/esr_dashboard/templates/esr_dashboard/esr_msg_detail.html')`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a relative path to your html fragment, the browser will try to locate your file in the current directory, not find it, and return a 404

if your file structure is:

```
├─script.js
├─subdirectory
│ ├─fragment.html
```

you'd need to reference it as `"./subdirectory/fragment.html"`

edit: if your file is in a directory above in the file tree, you use `"../"` to go up a directory

therefore, for your case what you'd want is: `"../../esr_dashboard/templates/esr_dashboard/esr_msg_detail.html"`, two "../" because you're going from the js/ to static/, and from static/ to EGHub/

Comment: I am located at http://localhost:8000/esr_dashboard/request_details/469/ when I click the link, it returns the 404 with the following http://localhost:8000/esr_dashboard/request_details/469/esr_dashboard/esr_msg_detail.html

Comment: then you need to use "./esr_dashboard/est_msg_detail.html", like I stated in the answer, you need to specify the precise path, not just give it the name of the file. the browser will look for the file in the same directory as your script and not find it, so you need to tell the browser to look in the subdirectory

Comment: I edited my question based on your initial suggestion. I'm struggling with how to tell the browser to "go back" up the tree to get to the desired directory.

Comment: ohh I see, I edited the answer to fit your issue

Comment: Still getting a similar error in the console  http://localhost:8000/esr_dashboard/esr_dashboard/templates/esr_dashboard/esr_msg_detail.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: then the structure you've given must not be exactly the one you've got, but I've already given you the tools, use "../" to navigate backwards, if you simply compose the path from your app to this fragment, it works